# Are there any GUI toolkits that exist as a C DLL?

Tags: c, user-interface, dll, toolkit

Are there any pre-built GUI toolkits that exist as a C DLL?

So i can simply import a static library and start using GUI commands to build an application written in C? Also so i can redistribute the dll with my application.

EDIT: Preferably with no dependencies or that they too are dlls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IUP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iup/files/3.5/Windows%20Libraries/) comes in pre-built packages. Scroll down to read which version you should get depending on which dependencies you want or which compiler you're using.

Note that your preference to have no dependencies is almost impossible considering that most toolkits will link against some `msvcr***.dll`, IDE-specific libs, or other lower-level open-source libs.

Realistically though, you should probably just pick your favourite toolkit and then compile it yourself along with all the dependencies, put them all into a folder, and that folder is what you link against to use the toolkit. Once you do that initial compilation it'll be just as easy to use as a precompiled one. Another advantage of compiling it yourself is you can pick which extras or extensions you wish to bundle in and which you won't need, which optimises the output filesize.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/)?

Comment: From the site: You will need the GLib, cairo, Pango, ATK, gdk-pixbuf and GTK+ developer packages to build software against GTK+. To run GTK+ programs you will also need the gettext-runtime, fontconfig, freetype, expat, libpng and zlib packages.

Comment: @GaryWilloughby nowhere in your question do you say that it can't have dependencies. Furthermore, I'll bet that if you looked someone out there has created a fully self-contained version of the library -- it's very popular after all.

Comment: 'So i can simply import a static library and start using GUI commands to build an application written in C?'

Comment: @GaryWilloughby static != self contained. You'd better believe there are static versions of gtk+.